# Do we need directory structure logic for storing millions of images on Amazon S3/Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

In order to support millions of potential images we have previously followed this sort of directory structure:

/profile/avatars/44/f2/47/48px/44f247d4e3f646c66d4d0337c6d415eb.jpg

The filename is md5 hashed, then we extract the first 6 characters in the string and build the folder structure from that.

So in the above example the filename:

`44f247d4e3f646c66d4d0337c6d415eb.jpg`

produces a directory structure of:

```
/44/f2/47/
```

We always did this in order to minimize the number of photos in any single directory, ultimately to aid filesystem performance.

**However our new app is using Amazon S3 with Cloudfront**

My understanding is that any folders you create on Amazon S3 are actually just references and are not directories on the filesystem.

If that is correct is it still recommended to split into folders/directories in the above, or similar method? Or can we simply remove this complexity in our application code and provide image links like so:

```
/profile/avatars/48px/filename.jpg
```

Baring in mind that this app is intended to serve 10's of millions of photos.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although S3 folders are basically only another way of writing the key name (as @E.J.Brennan already said in his answer), there *are* reasons to think about the naming structure of your "folders".

With your current number of photos and probably your access patterns, it might make sense to think about a way to speed up the S3 keyname lookups, making sure that operations on photos get spread out over multiple partitions. There is a [great article on the AWS blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html) explaining all the details.

Comment: After thoroughly reading that article I realised that the advice posted in it answers my question better than E.J. Brennans answer itself.  Therefore I have re-awarded the answer to yourself.  Hopefully he wont mind :)  Thanks again!

Comment: This is impressive, thank you so much for sharing. By the way, they moved & updated the article to [a separate documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to setup that structure on s3 unless you are doing it for your own convenience. All of the folders you create on s3 are really just an illusion for you, the files are stored in one big continuous container, so if you don't have a reason to organize the files in a pseudo-folder hierarchy, then don't bother.

If you needed to control access to different groups of people, based on you folder struture, that might be a reason to keep the structure, but besides that there probably isn't a benefit/